# Can switch statements in c# only take integer values?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

So, I am a beginner programmer in C#. I was trying to learn to use switch statements in C#. Having coming from python, I had no idea what they were. Anyway, my problem is that when I try to use a switch statement, they say that they cannot convert the string to an int. I don't understand why this is. Can C# only handle switch statements where the case values are ints?

Would be great if someone can provide some insight.

Error given is: cannot implicitly convert string to int

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch "The match expression" section

Answer (score 1):

No,

> In C# 6 and earlier, the match expression must be an expression that returns a value of the following types:
>
> a char, a string, a bool, an integral value - such as an int or a long, or an enum value.
>
> **Starting with C# 7.0, the match expression can be any non-null expression.**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#the-match-expression

Answer (score 0):

You can use Strings in switch statements, but it is more costly than just using ints since String are not primitive data types.

For more details, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#the-match-expression

Answer (score 0):

I guess you put the case value between double qoutations, for example if I write this code:

```
   //Wrong code
   int checkedItem = 0;
    switch(checkedItem)
    {
        case "0":
            //something
            break;
        case "1":
            //somethingg
            break;
    }
```

The code above gives cannot implicitly convert string to int error
You just need to remove qoutations around the case value as below:

```
           //Correct
           int checkedItem = 0;
            switch(checkedItem)
            {
                case 0:
                    //something
                    break;
                case 1:
                    //somethingg
                    break;
            }
```

I have just converted `case "0":` to `case 0:`